Failure running "sudo apt update": NO_PUBKEY C2850B265AC085BD error, where adding the key doesn't change anything
I have Ubuntu 18.04. I want to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version.
I get the following persistent error:
~> sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:10 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease [3,618 B]
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:10 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2850B265AC085BD
Hit:14 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2850B265AC085BD
E: The repository 'https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
The recommended key addition works, but does not change anything to the above error:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C2850B265AC085BD
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.P4CWQn3kFI/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C2850B265AC085BD
gpg: key D7B0B66941D01538: 2 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key D7B0B66941D01538: "riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1


The usual solution is to delete the source that is causing the error. You can re-add the source, if needed, after your release-upgrade is complete. It is much easier to release-upgrade while the keys are still valid.
